# How can I use my own image to replace the arrow for a select element in ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

ok so in ie8 it looks fine however I cant get it to look right in ie 7.

The styles below are the select div, the select element itself. How can I make it look like the ie 8 where the image instead of the tick is visible.

Select
                                                        Complaint

.........

```
select {
border: 1px solid #D1DEE8;
width: 333px;
padding: 0 40px 0 10px;
font-size: 12px;
color: #666;
line-height: 15px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
-webkit-border-radius: 0.5em;
-moz-appearance: none;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
-moz-border-radius: 0.5em;
background: #fff url(../images/selectDrop.png) no-repeat right center;
height: 33px;
```

........

```
.styled-select select {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
background: transparent;
width: 110%;
border: 0;
height: 32px;
float: left;
color: #666;
padding-top: 3px;
```

.......

```
.styled-select {
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
background: url(../images/DownArrow.png) white no-repeat 173px center;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-ms-border-radius: 7px;
-o-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't yet a cross-browser compatible route of styling form elements with CSS: it's not usually left to the designer to have control over their appearance/behaviour so form elements are notoriously difficult to style. Many browsers specifically do not allow you to style them at all!

If you need to get a consistent look across all browsers, the only route is to use JavaScript to replace the form element in-view with stylised HTML elements.

Here's an article that lists a few of the options available for you: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/